# Switches connected to one another

Tags: switch

This question is mainly about the logic of unmanaged switches.

I've seen posts here and elsewhere saying that it's okay to plug in a switch to a SOHO router (using a crossover if necessary), which is basically the same as plugging a switch into a switch.  I need to do this for a business to extend the amount of ethernet ports on their router.

I don't understand how this is possible.  Won't the router see many computers connected to one port, thus resetting what mac address it thinks is at that port every time a new message is sent?  I would think that would have performance consequences, unless I'm wrong here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any non-braindead switch implementation understands multiple MAC addresses per port. What you're proposing doing is fine, and perfectly normal.

(Your SOHO router is actually a router and a switch combined into one device)

Comment: And the router part of the device only cares about Layer 3: source and destination address, the switch takes care of what port has what MAC, etc.

Comment: Thanks derobert and gravyface.  That's exactly the answer I needed.

Comment: Of course there is a limit to the number of physical address.  A cheap switch may have a relatively small [cam table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAM_Table) so if you added a couple thousand computers your switch might start acting like a hub.